# How do I prove that $AB = BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two $n × n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to be simultaneously diagonalizable if there exists an invertible $n × n$ matrix $S$ such that $S^{−1}AS$ and $S^{−1}BS$ are both diagonal.

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable $n × n$ matrices, then $AB = BA$

My attempt: if A and B are simultaneously diagonalizable, then there exists an invertible $n × n$ matrix $S$ such that $S^{−1}AS$ and $S^{−1}BS$ are both diagonal (given).

$A = S^{−1}AS$
$B = S^{−1}BS$

$AB  = S^{−1}AS \times S^{−1}BS  = BA = S^{−1}BS \times S^{−1}AS$

Is that a sufficient proof? I think I am going wrong somewhere...

Comment: It should be clear that there's something wrong with any proof that says $A = S^{−1}AS$ in general. This can only be true if $A$ is already a diagonal matrix, which is a much stronger condition than you're supposed to use.

Comment: The hint is that when $S$ is invertible, then $AB = BA$ if and only if $(SAS^{-1})(SBS^{-1}) = (SBS^{-1})(SAS^{-1})$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, your proof is incorrect: You're assuming that $A = S^{-1} A S$, which is *not* true - after all, based on the assumption you'd need to have $A$ be diagonal, which is too strong.

The only thing that is true is that there is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = S^{-1} A S$, and likewise some diagonal $E$ with $E = S^{-1} B S$.

Now with the correct setup, the main idea of your proof goes through:

$$AB = S^{-1} D S S^{-1} E S = S^{-1} DE S$$

Now if you could write $DE = ED$, you'd be done: reinsert the term $SS^{-1}$ and write down $BA$.

So why can you do this? It's important that $D$ and $E$ are diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable means that $\exists D,E$ both diagonals matrix such as $A=SDS^{−1}$ and $B=SES^{−1}$.
Finally you can have your result because two diagonal matrix are commutative.